# how to call another subroutine after the return statement

Tags: perl, moose, mojolicious

How can I call another subroutine from existing subroutine just after the return statement in perl.
I dont want to call before the return statement as it is taking time to render. I do not want to wait. return it and then call another subroutine before the exit. Is it possible in perl?

Comment: Please explain your problem better. As stated, your request makes no  sense. You can't do something before the sub is exited but after it executes a `return`, because the whole point of `return` is to exit the sub.

Comment: Write a wrapper for the routine from which you want to return without undue wait, in which you call that routine (and so it returns) and then call the other one.

Comment: Can I use hook feature of Mojolicious?

Comment: @zdim Can you please give me an example of what you are suggesting

Comment: It sounds like what you want is an `after` method modifier. If you use Moose inside of Mojolicious, you have the Moose implementation available. If you don't, you could use Class::Method::Modifiers. If you're talking about Actions in Mojo, I am not sure what willl happen if you combine that. If you can alter the sub you want something to execute after, you can always go `return do{ foo(); $original_return_value }`

Comment: Thanks @simbabque. But can I do something like return do{$original_return_value;  foo() }

Comment: That would discard the original return value and return the return value of `foo()`. So that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Like `sub wrapper { original();  slow() };` and add handling of returns etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `fork` and run your subroutine in a new process while the original process is returning.

```
sub do_something {
    my ($var1, $var2, $var3) = @_;
    my $output = ...

    if (fork() == 0) {
        # child process
        do_something_else_that_takes_a_long_time();
        exit;
    }
    # still the parent process
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That serves the need

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged as Moose, so here is how you do what you want with a [*method modifier*](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers.pod). The [`after` modifier](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose#after-$name%7C@names%7C%5C@names%7Cqr/.../-=%3E-sub-%7B-...-%7D) runs after a sub is, but its return value is ignored.

```
package Foo;
use Moose;

sub frobnicate {
  my $self = shift;

  # ...

  return 123;
}

after frobnicate => sub {
  my ($self, $rv) = @_;

  $self->barnicate;
};

1;
```

Now whenever `frobnicate` is done, `barnicate` will be called.